# IONIC: Failed to load resource: unsupported URL

Tags: cordova, camera, ionic-framework

i am developing a Instagram-like App with ionic and with iOS9 i am getting a strange error, i looked for a solution in the web but i didnt find something helpful. The strange thing is, the Filters at the bottom of the screen are using the same image, but there it is working.

and GapDebug is throwing this error:

Failed unsafe:file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/AC45E204-30FB-4F61-92DF-97B840149D7D/tmp/cdv_photo_002.jpg to load resource: unsupported URL

[Screenshot from the App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JJHd.png)

> Solution: 
>   add this to your .config in app.js
>
> $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|file|mailto|chrome-extension):/);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely not using a version number, which is forcing you to use [white-lists](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-whitelist). Set your Cordova compiler version to before 4.0.0, like maybe *3.7.1* **_OR_** setup, the `white-list`, the `white-list plugin`, and the `CSP` (see bottom of docs)

Comment: thank you! i found out, that i was using whit-lists, but this line was missing:

Comment: $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s(https|ftp|file|mailto|chrome-extension):/);

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting this error on an `img` `src` then this might be the whitelist config you're looking for: `$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|ftp|mailto|content|file|assets-library):|data:image\//);`

Comment: How and where to put in the xml blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to the `<head>` of your `index.html`:

```
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
    default-src 'self' data: gap: *;
    script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
    style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
    media-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *;
    img-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' * data:;">
```